# three.js light didn't render under Apache server on chrome

Tags: javascript, apache, tomcat, three.js

this image describes the problem

```
var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.65,0);
    pointLight.position.set(0, 300, -250);
    scene.add(pointLight);
var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xfff4f2);
    scene.add(light);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add some code that you tried, it is difficult to understand your problem.

Comment: the problem not in code it run in python server but when running it in apache didn't run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upgrade server and try again !!

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have texture path problems under a different server. Check the net panel in browser Developer tools to see whether the textures have incorrect URL or some other problem causing them to not load.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but all textures have correct URL and loaded